# How do I change the Grab Button and "Button" Click button on Oculus Touch controllers?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, oculus

The default buttons for grab is "Axis1D.PrimaryHandTrigger" and for the button click is "Button.One". Although these are the default ones, I would like to change the settings so it can take in different inputs.

I could not find where and how the input is added to these OVR touch controllers.

Comment: Why do you want to change the default settings? You can assign different methods to different input instead.

Comment: How do I do that?

Comment: From your script. Lets say you have two methods, Jump() and Run(). Its your choice whether you want to call any of them with any button on VR crontroller

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this [official docs](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/OculusControllers.html) by unity for VR inputs with their Unity Axes IDs.

Go to the Project Settings and select Input. There you can change one of the input for your custom VR input as shown in the picture below:

[image]

Also change the Axis from Y axis to 11th axis (joystick) and untick Invert. See the picture below:

[image]

Now you can call them in your script like this example:

```
void Update()
    {
        if(Input.GetAxis("Vertical") == 1)
        {
            //Do something
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks you this helped!